# Perform animation in android with a set timeline on different layout elements

Tags: android, animation

I have 5 TextViews and I need to apply animation on them using a fixed timeline. For example the duration of first animation is 233 ms but the second animation should start at 200 ms. Similarly, third animation should start 400ms even if other animations are going on. Please can someone help me find an optimal way of doing it.

Thanks,
Colin

Comment: Take a look at `ValueAnimator` and `ObjectAnimator` in the `android.animation` package.  Also check out the sample animation code in the SDK at samples/android-<api>/legacy/ApiDemos.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What I ended up doing was giving different startOffset time to all the animations.